# Prove a number is pseudoprime with Sophie Germain

Tags: chinese-remainder-theorem, pseudoprimes

Let p be a Sophie Germain prime. Let q = 2p + 1. Let a = −q − 2p. Given that q ≡ 3
(mod p − 1), prove that pq is a pseudoprime to base a.

I want to show pq is pseudoprime to base a but I am struggling as p is Sophie Germain.
$$q = 2p + 1$$ $$ a = -q-2p$$ $$q=3(mod(p-1))$$

I thought I could use Chinese Remainder Theorem but will unknowns not concrete values I am struggling making any progress in this way. I have my definition for pseudoprime as $a^n=a(modn)$ so any further advice would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a^{pq}-1=a(a^{pq-1}-1)=a(a^{\frac{pq-1}2}-1)(a^{\frac{pq-1}2}+1)$$

Due to Euler's criterion:

$a^{\frac{pq-1}2-1}-1 \equiv 0 \bmod pq$, if $a\equiv x^2 \bmod pq$

$a^{\frac{pq-1}2-1}+1 \equiv 0 \bmod pq$, if $a\not\equiv x^2 \bmod pq$

Hence in any case :

$a^{pq}-1\equiv 0 \bmod pq$

Example:

$p=11$, $q=2\cdot 11 +1=23$

$a=-23-2\times 22=-45$

$(-45)^{\frac{(23\times 11=253)-1}2 }=45^{126}$

$45^{126}=(45^2)^{63}$

$45^2=2025=(8\times 253 +1)\equiv 1 \bmod 253 $

Therefore:

$(a=-45)^{126}-1\equiv 0 bmod 253$

that is:

$(-45)^{11\times23}-(-45)\equiv 0\bmod (11\times 23)$

Comment: This is equivalent to $a^{n-1}-1\equiv 0 \bmod n$.

Comment: Thank you for this response! I was wondering if you could help (warning this is probably a silly question) my definition for pseudoprime has $a^n=a(modn)$ so is this equivalent to $a^n-1=0(modn)$? I'm just struggling to get my head around this bit